# How to diagnose Stack Overflow in haskell

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

I've written a haskell program, which does stuff on 10000 things. Now, just for the hell of it I ran it with a million and got a `stack space overflow`.

I am aware of the foldr/foldl issue and the problems which can be caused by laziness, but I currently have no clue which piece of my code is causing this.

What is a good way to attack such problems?

Comment: Real World Haskell has a chapter on profiling space leaks: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to profiling space usage in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426266/is-it-possible-to-profiling-space-usage-in-haskell)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Debug.Trace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html) module to be useful for such things. Without seeing any of your code, it's difficult to give a useful example, but if you look at that documentation you can probably find something that will help.

Otherwise, I would examine your code for non-tail recursions that could be filling up the call stack.

Comment: Non-tail recursion isn't the only thing that can cause a stack overflow in Haskell.  We must also look for "thunk buildup" (which, unfortunately, can be more subtle)

Comment: Who could forget about the thunks? +1 But I did think that thunks went on the heap and not the stack.

Comment: They are allocated on the heap, but the stack is used when evaluating them.

Comment: With a non-strict language like Haskell, tail recursion is more likely to cause a stack overflow than it is to prevent it.