# Primitive but efficient grep clone in haskell?

Tags: regex, haskell, grep

Whenever I consider learning a new language -- haskell in this case -- I try to hack together a primitive grep clone to see how good the language implementation and/or its libraries are at text processing, because that's a major use case for me.

Inspired by [code on the haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_Unix_tools), I came up with the following naive attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Text.Regex.PCRE
import System.Environment

io :: ([String] -> [String]) -> IO ()
io f = interact (unlines . f . lines)

regexBool :: forall r l .
  (RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption r,
   RegexLike Regex l) =>
  r -> l -> Bool
regexBool r l = l =~ r :: Bool

grep :: forall r l .
  (RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption r, RegexLike Regex l) =>
  r -> [l] -> [l]
grep r = filter (regexBool r)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  argv <- getArgs
  io $ grep $ argv !! 0
```

This appears to be doing what I want it to, but unfortunately, it's *really* slow -- about 10 times slower than a python script doing the same thing. I assume it's not the regex library that's at fault here, because it's calling into PCRE which should be plenty fast (switching to `Text.Regex.Posix` slows things down quite a bit further). So it must be the `String` implementation, which is instructive from a theoretical point of view but inefficient according to what I've read.

Is there an alternative to `String`s in haskell that's both efficient and convenient (i.e. there's little or no friction when switching to using that instead of `String`s) and that fully and correctly handles UTF-8-encoded Unicode, as well as other encodings without too much hassle if possible? Something that everybody uses when doing text processing in haskell but that I just don't know about because I'm a complete beginner?

Comment: Use [Text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that getting C-like speeds is possible, but it might take some effort. Have a look at  __cgrep__ - http://awgn.github.io/cgrep/

Comment: `String` is a low-performance, lazy string, which is "fine" for basic short strings but unsuitable for serious text manipulation. `Text` is the high-performance type for Unicode text manipulation. (There's also `ByteString` which is _not_ for text but for byte sequences.)

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: @amalloy: I wasn't aware of optimizations, thanks for pointing them out to me! Unfortunately, in this particular case, the difference seems to be negligible...

Comment: @ErikR, @chi: Thanks for the breakdown and the pointers, cgrep looks well worth investigating! Would either of you perhaps take a shot at modifying my example code to work with `Text`? I'd be happy to accept that as an answer. I'm trying to do so myself but I can't get my program to typecheck, so I must be missing something :(

Comment: i think you should try this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the slow speed is caused by using the standard library's list type. I've often run into performance problems with it in the past.

It would be a good idea to profile your executable, to see where it spends its time: [Tools for analyzing performance of a Haskell program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276240/tools-for-analyzing-performance-of-a-haskell-program). Profiling Haskell programs is really easy (compile with a switch and execute your program with an added argument, and the report is written to a text file in the current working directory).

As a side note, I use exactly the same approach as you when learning a new language: create something that works. My experience doing this with Haskell is that I can easily gain an order of magnitude or two in performance by profiling and making relatively simple changes (usually a couple of lines).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know haskell had such nice profiling support out of the box! Looks like I'm spending about two thirds of the time in `io` and one third in `regexBool` (see above), so no real surprises here -- I just need to make those calls faster... Which should by doable by using `Text` instead of `String` as pointed out by other commenters above; only trouble is, I haven't been able to get my program to typecheck with this modification so far.

Comment: @dlukes - depends on which regex-library you are using - I think regex-heavy has `Text` support the others seem to be `String`/`ByteString` only but maybe with inlining this is good enough for your needs.