# Return true if list has only even numbers with foldr

Tags: list, haskell

I would like to have a function that checks if a list contains only even numbers; if so, it should return `True`, otherwise - `False`.

Functions I would like to use are `map` / `filter` / `foldr`, possibly without `length`.

Here is my attempt:

```
ListOfeven :: [Integral] -> Bool
ListOfeven xs = 
  | foldr (+) True filter odd xs < 0 = True
  | otherwise = False
```

I am pretty sure that there is a cleaner way.. isn't there any? :)

Comment: To work from what you gave. First of all the guards are redundant

Comment: So, accidentally hit enter on last comment: reposting -- To work from what you gave. First of all the guards are redundant, also instead of checking whether the sum is nonzero, we can just check if the filtered list is non null (also your code has a bug, it fails for the list [0]). So the `foldr (+)` and `< 0` drops out and instead put in `not . null . filter odd`. Well `null . filter` == `any` so this turns into `not . all odd`. And `not . any foo` == `all (not . foo)` and since `not . odd` == `even`, we end up with the answer @Frerich Raabe gave `all even`. Hope that helps :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest would be to just use the [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aall) function from the Prelude:

```
evenList = all even
```

If you insist on just using [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap), [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afilter) and [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr):

```
evenList = foldr (&&) True . map even
```

Answer (score 5):

```
myfunc = foldr (\a b -> even a && b) True
```

Answer (score 1):

Frerich's solution works well, but can be optimized just a touch:

```
evenList :: [Integer] -> Bool
evenList = foldr ((&&) . even) True
```

This will only run through the list once. The function composition here is a bit strange, but becomes more clear upon examining its type:

```
(&&) . even :: Integral a => a -> Bool -> Bool
```

The result of `even`, which takes a single argument, is then bound to the first argument to the `&&` operator, used here in prefix notation.

Comment: Did you benchmark this? I believe that `foldr  (&&) True . map even` will also iterate the list just once because of stream fusion. See [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578063/what-is-haskells-stream-fusion) for what that is and how it works.

Comment: Awesome! I suppose I should have done more extensive homework! Will investigate further.