# I_AMAX in Haskell and other Programming Languages -- RANGE

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, functional-programming, range, blas

Is there a concept of range in Haskell or other functional programming languages?  Suppose I want to compute I_AMAX from BLAS (to find the smallest index of the largest element in vector x).  A naive method would be something like

```
idamax x idx = foldr(imax) 0 (zip x idx)
```

where idx is the index vector and imax returns the tuple with the smallest index and largest value.

For example, some vector (say, [1, 7, 3, 5]), zipped with its index vector ([0, 1, 2, 3], which makes [(1, 0), (7, 1), (3, 2), (5, 2)]), then reduced with the maximum function (so (7, 1), or 7).

But the index knowledge should be implicit, since in a loop the index is self-evident.  Is there a way to write this in Haskell?

tl;dr, what's the best way to write I_AMAX in Haskell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version:

```
idamax :: Ord a => [a] -> Int
idamax = negate . snd . maximum . flip zip [0, -1..]
```

#### Explanation

First note that `zip`ping to lists yields a list with length of the shortest input list. So we can use `[0..]` to attach natural indices to list elements:

```
zip [0..] [1, 7, 3, 5] = [(0, 1), (1, 7), (2, 3), (3, 5)]
```

So what we do is:

1. attach an (negated) index to each element in a list
2. find a pair with max value and least index (which is max here because of previous negation)
3. extract index from resulting pair
4. negate it back

For example, starting with `[1, 4, 2, 4]`:

1. attach index: `[(1, 0), (4, -1), (2, -2), (4, -3)]`
2. find maximum: `(4, -1)` (note that `(4, -1) > (4, -3)`)
3. extract index: `-1`
4. negate: `1`

#### Examples

```
>>> idamax [1..10]
9
>>> idamax [1, 3, 4, 2, 4]
2
>>> idamax "oh hello"
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response--but is there a way to compute it without having to generate the array? [0, -1..]

Comment: @xiii1408 this is list (not array) and it will be fused by compiler in this case (i.e. it won't exist as a whole at runtime), because `maximum` needs only one pass and `zip` can yield resulting list incrementally (one element per time). This is a basic optimisation called "list fusion" (or "stream fusion"). Check this another SO question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578063/what-is-haskells-stream-fusion

Comment: An infinite index list is *the* idiomatic Haskell way to deal with things like loop counters.