# Are there infinite lists with unboxed vector performance?

Tags: haskell, signal-processing, lazy-evaluation

I'm thinking specifically for signal processing. Let's say I wanted to do something like double the magnitude of an incoming signal. I would want it to be very fast, so I would want the signal to be held in contiguous memory (e.g. unboxed vectors). But this signal could go on indefinitely, so I would want it to be treated as an infinite list; I'd rather call `map (*2) signal` once instead of calling it for every signal chunk.

Is there a data structure in Haskell that would buffer these data chunks so that I could get contiguous memory performance, but treat the data as an infinite stream?

Comment: [I explored whether it's feasible to design a DSP library this way a while ago](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/timed-media/blob/master/Media/Timed/Audio.hs). (I think it is, at least you can build some cheesy example melody things... but I've not done much serious work on it.) A chunked infinite list, but without all that time-bookkeeping would be an interesting project on its own right.

Comment: Lazy bytestrings do this, except they can only hold bytes.  Internally, a lazy bytestring is a list of unboxed arrays.  I don't know of a similar library for other data types.

Comment: Lazy bytestrings seems to be exactly what I'm asking for. It seems like [this library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/storablevector-0.2.8.3/docs/Data-StorableVector-Lazy.html) attempts to do the same thing but with arbitrary elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a long shot, but what about using [streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/docs/Data-Stream.html) of large enough chunks of unboxed vectors? This would have the advantage of vectors' performance, and at the same time, [fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/578063/1333025) thanks to streams.

**Update:** The idea is to define a `newtype` such as:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Stream
import Data.Word

newtype Word8Stream = Word8Stream (Stream (UArray Int Word8))
```

and then define the generic functions you need such as

```
smap :: (Word8 -> Word8) -> Word8Stream -> Word8Stream
smap f (Word8Stream s) = Word8Stream $ fmap (amap f) s
```

Comment: This solves the performance issue, but I can't treat the stream of chunks as one long list (or vector), can I? I would have to use map.map, instead of one invocation of map, if I wanted to apply a function that expects a vector of elements, right?

Comment: @DurnWhippersnapper You're right, but that can be hidden in a `newtype` data type and a set of corresponding functions, so that the internal implementation is completely opaque to other modules. I updated the answer.

Comment: Just make it a functor.

Comment: @PyRulez Functor probably won't be possible, as for performance reasons the data type most likely won't be polymorphic. However, [ListLike](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike) could be used for this, as it supports monomorphic types as well.

Comment: What does polymorphism matter?

Comment: @PyRulez `Functor` instances must be fully polymorphic.

Comment: Well sure, but how does polymorphism hurt performance. Types are inferred, type-checked, and then done away with once you compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56489/discussion-between-petr-pudlak-and-pyrulez).